# How do I see the current filter being applied in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I received an Excel document with a filter already applied. The header row does not show the dropdown buttons. RIght now I can uncheck the filter to see the entire dataset, and then hit undo to go back to the original view. Is it possible for me to see what the filter is so I can do more with the file?

Comment: If the drop down is not available in the header column, it means filter is not applied. But since you say you are able to clear the filter and see all rows, make sure you are referring to the header row correctly!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what version of Excel you are working with. Is the file you received the same version you are working in? Sometimes version conflicts will mess with filters, formats and views, etc.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010, but I don't know what the source file is created with, other than that it's in xlsx format.

Comment: @jjk_charles The original view goes straight from row 1 to row 71, and I can clear the filter to see the rows in between. How do I check if I'm referring to the header row correctly?

Comment: @Lupius, in a simple table with filters, all of the filters are in row `1`, as seen here: http://snag.gy/Hr2Id.jpg How does your spreadsheet differ from my image?

Comment: @Lupius If you manage to find header row where the filter is applied, you should be able to identify the column(s) over which filter is applied by the difference in drop down image used on header row. If a filter is applied, it would appear like [this image](http://officeimg.vo.msecnd.net/en-us/files/568/826/ZA010186550.gif)

Comment: It's possible someone has used the advanced filter option (which doesn't change the header row.  Select a cell in the table and try clicking the advanced button under data>sort&Filter>Advanced and see if there is anything in the criteria range.  If there is see what is in those cells.

Comment: @gtwebb Thanks for the tip! There was nothing in the criteria range, but clicking on the advanced button showed the list range and changed the view, which showed the filter dropdown at cell S1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by gtwebb, the advanced filter dialog box showed a list range of `Sheet1!$S$1`, and led me to find the filter in `Column S`.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover your mouse over the filter button you should see a text box indicating the current filter used.

[image]

I'm using Excel 2016.

Comment: The question is about how to do this when the filter buttons are not being shown (although I admit I don't know how that could happen).

Answer (score 0):

every time there is filter applied, the row numbers [left side] will be in blue font color. If dat is REALLY filtered you will see that. If the row numbers are in black then no filters are applied. If you suspect some rows are HIDDEN, then you can unhide rows. hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite answering the OP, but thanks for a helpful answer to my related question.